# Reference to the Active Cell in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, cell

How do I reference to the Active Cell in a macro?

For example if I want to open a document with the name of the Active Cells value.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
"F:\AKTIVITETER\2014\TKC14066_XXX_HELMASKIN-BULLERDATABAS_BULLER\LJUDRAPPORTER\??????.xls"
```

Comment: The active cell is just `ActiveCell` so its value is `ActiveCell.Value`

Answer (score 0):

ActiveCell does the trick :) Like this:

```
Workbooks.Open (ActiveCell.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

To Use your code do this:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= ActiveCell.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the string:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim txt As String
    txt = ActiveCell.Value
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "F:\AKTIVITETER\2014\TKC14066_XXX_HELMASKIN-BULLERDATABAS_BULLER\LJUDRAPPORTER\" & txt & ".xls"
End Sub
```